# Adding innerHTML positioned before the existing HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Instead of this method which adds more HTML *after* the existing HTML of an element,

`document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += 'new html';`

`<div id="div1">old html new html</div>`

Is there a way to insert it *before* the existing HTML?

`document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += 'new html';`

`<div id="div1">new html old html</div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simply:

```
 var oldHTML = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "New HTML" + oldHTML;
```